# What are the last_updated, last_pushed and tag_last_pushed dates of Docker images?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

From the docker hub api endpoint [https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/{namespace}/repositories/{repository}/tags/{tag}](https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/%7Bnamespace%7D/repositories/%7Brepository%7D/tags/%7Btag%7D), we can get information related to a specific image tag

```
{
"id": 0,
"images": {
"architecture": "string",
"features": "string",
"variant": "string",
"digest": "string",
"layers": [],
"os": "string",
"os_features": "string",
"os_version": "string",
"size": 0,
"status": "active",
"last_pulled": "2021-01-05T21:06:53.506400Z",
"last_pushed": "2021-01-05T21:06:53.506400Z"
},
"creator": 0,
"last_updated": "2021-01-05T21:06:53.506400Z",
"last_updater": 0,
"last_updater_username": "string",
"name": "string",
"repository": 0,
"full_size": 0,
"v2": "string",
"status": "active",
"tag_last_pulled": "2021-01-05T21:06:53.506400Z",
"tag_last_pushed": "2021-01-05T21:06:53.506400Z"
}
```

However, the fields are not well documented. What is the difference between last_updated, tag_last_pushed and last_pushed fields and what do they really mean?

Answer (score 1):

last_pushed is the last time that an image with any tag has been pushed to the repo, but tag_last_pushed is the last time an image with the specific tag given in the API was pushed to repo.

Comment: and what is the last_updated? is it different than tag_last_pushed? @SobhanRM